# JQuery Themeroller alternatives

Tags: jquery, themeroller

The [JQuery ThemeRoller](https://jqueryui.com/themeroller/) is not working since many months now. Whenever you try do download a theme, you'll get an error:

```
Error 502 Ray ID: 5c0dbbed7810b30e • 2020-08-11 00:10:32 UTC
Bad gateway
```

Is there any other alternative out there? I've had to edit JQ themes manually, but it takes a very long time since you have to edit the css files and also create all the needed image files (very tricky). It has become a nightmare to achieve this, and it used to be so simple all the years that themeroller was working.

I thought I would find a lot of comments regarding this subject on here, however, I didn't find any. The JQuery forum is not working either. All they mention is that "it has been reported".

is there another way to achieve what themeroller used to do? am I the only one using JQuery on 2020?

Any help will be really appreciated.

Comment: Also see [Download Builder gives Error 502](https://github.com/jquery/download.jqueryui.com/issues/359) : "Seems like they just gave up on it."

Comment: Am looking for this as well. Did you find any alternatives other than manually fixing the theme?

Comment: Sadly, I did not. I had to edit the background images manually etc. If you happen to find any alternative, please post it here. Good luck!!!